# GXT Not working

Tags: javascript, gwt, gxt

I am quite new to GWT and GXT and i tried makina a very simple application, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my onModuleLoad() method. Instead of getting a nice layout with collapsible elements, it seems like it all collapses into the left part. The elements exist because when i inspect them with the js-console on IE, they seems to be there, but the layout is off. Could you tell me what i did wrong?

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Viewport viewport =new Viewport();
    final BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
    viewport.setLayout(borderLayout);

    BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.NORTH);
    northData.setCollapsible(false);
    northData.setSplit(false);

    HTML headerHtml = new HTML();
    headerHtml.setHTML("<h1>RSS Reader</h1>");
    viewport.add(headerHtml,northData);

    BorderLayoutData centerData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.CENTER);
    centerData.setCollapsible(false);

    BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(Style.LayoutRegion.WEST,200,150,300);
    westData.setCollapsible(true);
    westData.setSplit(true);

    ContentPanel mainPanel = new ContentPanel();
    ContentPanel navPanel = new ContentPanel();

    viewport.add(mainPanel,centerData);
    viewport.add(navPanel,westData);

    RootPanel.get().add(viewport);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example at http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout shows that you can add **one** widget to `ViewPort` and this probably must be `BorderLayoutContainer`. And after that you begin to add to this container your widgets with `BorderLayoutData`.